# Dante server not starting on Raspberry

Tags: ubuntu, debian, socks, dante

I am trying to setup Dante SOCKS server on my Raspberry 3. I tried a clean install of Debian Buster and Ubuntu 19.10. On both systems I get the following error right after server installation with the default config:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu ~> sudo systemctl start danted
Job for danted.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status danted.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
ubuntu@ubuntu ~> sudo systemctl status danted
● danted.service - SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted)
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/danted.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-03-19 18:04:15 UTC; 1s ago
     Docs: man:danted(8)
           man:danted.conf(5)
  Process: 1572 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c         uid=`sed -n -e "s/[[:space:]]//g" -e "s/#.*//" -e "/^user\.privileged/{s/[^:]*://p;q;}" /etc/danted.conf`;      if [ -n "$uid" ]; then                  touch /var/run/danted.pid;              chown

Mar 19 18:04:15 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted)...
Mar 19 18:04:15 ubuntu systemd[1572]: danted.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: No such file or directory
Mar 19 18:04:15 ubuntu systemd[1572]: danted.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /bin/sh: No such file or directory
Mar 19 18:04:15 ubuntu systemd[1]: danted.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE
Mar 19 18:04:15 ubuntu systemd[1]: danted.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 19 18:04:15 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted).
```

*Output from Ubuntu v19.10, Dante v1.4.2*
What can I do to solve this issue?

**Update:** I had Dante working on one of previous versions of Debian (probably Stretch) on the same device

Comment: I have the same problem. Don't want to go back on a previous version of Raspbian. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I've seen in different project, it seems to be a badly packaged version. So we need to make a ticket with debian/ubuntu/Raspbian about this packet to warn the maintainers.
In the mean time, here is a partial solution that I've retrieved from [here](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/1073).
You can start danted as a simple process.

```
sudo danted
```

You can maybe use a bash script in the mean time by including it in screen/tmux session.

Answer (score 3):

edit the file

```
 sudo vim /lib/systemd/system/danted.service
```

find the line

> ReadOnlyDirectories=/bin /etc /lib /lib64 /sbin /usr /var

and change /lib64 to -/lib64

> ReadOnlyDirectories=/bin /etc /lib -/lib64 /sbin /usr /var

save (ctrl+x y enter) now run

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo /etc/init.d/danted start
```

this was suggested by Anatoly A. Kazantsev at https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1688336.html

some debian distros don't have the /lib64 folder.